# How to remove specific repeated characters from text?

Tags: java, regex

I have a String like

```
"this is line 1\n\n\nthis is line 2\n\n\nthis is line 3\t\t\tthis is line 3 also"
```

What I want to do is remove repeated specific characters like "\n", "\t" from this text.

```
"this is line 1\nthis is line 2\nthis is line 3\tthis is line 3 also"
```

I tried some regular expressions but didn't work for me.

```
text = text.replace("/[^\\w\\s]|(.)\\1/gi", "");
```

Is there any regex for this?

Comment: @anubhava this is java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to only remove *sepcific* whitespace chars, `\s` won't help as it will overmatch, i.e. it will also match spaces, hard spaces, etc.

You may use a character class with the chars, wrap them with a capturing group and use a backreference to the value captured. And replace with the backreference to the Group 1  value:

```
.replaceAll("([\n\t])\\1+", "$1")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gZmBCv/1).

**Details**

- `([\n\t])` - Group 1 (referred to with `\1` from the pattern and `$1` from the replacement pattern): a character class matching either a newline or tab symbols
- `\1+` - one or more repetitions of the value in Group 1.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your code works perfectly. I have another problem now. "\t\n\t\nLine 1\t\n\tLine 2" my text looks like this. I want to replace it like "\t\nLine 1\t\nLine 2"

Comment: Ok, I see you already found the solution, `.replaceAll("\n\t\n", "\n\t")`

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Guava's `CharMatcher`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/StringsExplained#charmatcher):

```
CharMatcher.javaIsoControl().removeFrom(myString)
```